# Log4net is not running in my VS2012 unit tests

Tags: .net, unit-testing, log4net

I have Log4net working on my web application, but when I try to run my unit tests, I can't get the logging to work.

In my UnitTest project, my AssembyInfo.cs has the following:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

I have a log4net.config file in my UnitTest project:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net debug="true">
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="./SmvServiceTest.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maximumFileSize value="2MB" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I have this file set to *Copy to Output directory*.  Yet, when I run my unit test, they hit a lot of log statements, but no log file is created.

I think I have it all set up correctly, is there something special about the unit tests?  I just don't understand why it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**:

I think I've found the cause of the problem.  I went to the temporary location where the tests are run and found that the log4net.config is actually not there.  I don't know why it is not getting copied over, the Copy To Output directory is set to true in the file properties.

Comment: wouldn't you configure the log4net in the app.config for the test project?  The web project is never initialized, so no settings are loaded from its web.config.

Comment: @ps2goat, I don't think so, I think the AssemblyInfo.cs setting tells the log4.net service which file to watch and reads the settings from there.  Unless it is somehow different for a UnitTest project...

Comment: @ps2goat, I added to the app.config and still no logging, thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. This solution fixed the issue. 

https://foldingair.blogspot.com/2009/04/log4net-inside-code-run-with-mstest.html

TLDR; The logging has to be initialized.

Answer (score 3):

If your config file is not being copied to the **out** folder of your unit test directory structure this probably will not work.  To copy config files you need to use the **DeploymentItem** attribute on your unit test.

example:

```
[TestClass, DeploymentItem("nhibernate_log4net.cfg.xml")]
public class Test
```

Answer (score 1):

All should work fine. Look for log file under `UnitTestProject\bin\Debug\` directory. Thus you are specifying relative path for file, log file will be created there.

Comment: It definitely should work, but the file is not there.  Works fine in my web project, and I suspect it is because I am configuring the watcher in the code.  It's almost as if the AssembyInfo.cs is ignored in the UnitTest project...

Comment: @MarkKadlec you should not configure `AssemblyInfo.cs` for UnitTest project. Add log4net configuration only to `AssemblyInfo.cs` of web project

Comment: @lazybrezovsky, that's fine, but where do I configure the config file watcher in the UnitTest Project?